# Images embedded in Articles not being displayed in migrated Joomla website

Tags: image, joomla

Images embedded in Articles not being displayed in migrated Joomla website

I have migrated a Joomla 3.7.2 website from an old server to a new server using a particularly messy  technique. Basically, I exported the database and then copied the important folders and it all worked remarkably well barring one very specific feature. Articles with images in them no longer display the images in the new site.

I have **System - SEF** enabled in both sites (and switching it off makes no difference)

I use JCE and in code view the typical line displaying the image looks like this:
`<p><img src="images/players/shirt.jpg" alt="" /></p>`
In both sites.

JCE is configured to use Relative URLs in both sites. If I turn that OFF then I get the image displayed in the new site. Of course that's just a hack around the problem not a solution to it.

*Path to Files Folder*, and *Path to Images Folder* is set to **images** in both sites.

HTML inspector on the old site shows the 
`<img src="/images/players/shirt.jpg" alt="Shirt">`

And on the new site
`<img src="images/players/shirt.jpg" alt="Shirt">`

And if you hover over the url it says "could not load the image". The missing first '/' is clearly the problem but what is it that puts it there after the article is saved by the editor and before the html is displayed in the browser?

Comment: You have insert .htaccess file of your last version of joomla? The RewriteBase / in this file is enable?

Comment: Thanks for the input but yes, I have .htaccess and no, Rewritebase  / is commented out. I did try uncommenting it just to see if it made any difference but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly embarrassed to pretend this is an answer but today I got the prompt to update Joomla to 3.7.3 and of course immediately afterwards the problem has gone away.